# What happens in the backend when one chooses Home, Work, or Public network?

Tags: windows, security

In the past, Windows often asked me to determine if the Wifi I just connected was a Home Network, Work Network, or Public Network. I didn't bother to find out the difference between them and usually chose one at random. Lately, I got a similar dialogue from Bitdefender. What's the difference if choose Home Network, Work Network, or Public Network?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you read the "Help me choose link"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft
[says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d):

> - **Private network**. Use this for networks you trust, such as a network at home or work. When a network is set to private, your PC is
>   discoverable to other devices on the network, and you can use your PC
>   for file and printer sharing.
> - **Public network**. Use this for networks you connect to when you’re out and about, such as a Wi-Fi network at a coffee shop. Your PC will
>   be hidden from other devices on the network, and you can’t use your PC
>   for file and printer sharing.

Home and Work networks are both considered as Private.

I recommend using the Home Network at home, Work at work,
and Public in coffee shops or when connecting to public wifi,
so as not to discard the protections that Windows supplies
to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

For many uses Home and Work are the same. Public is for unsecured Wireless, or somewhere that you do not know the security.

If your Work has specialized Wireless that consumer networks do not offer, and you are in a Home environment, then use the Home setting.

For myself, and my small business clients, there is nothing to choose between Home and Work.

For individuals and Home use, just use the Home setting.